# how to find nearest power in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

You are given two no A And B when A is raised to some power P we get a no X no I want to find the value of X that is closest to B
for example if input is 2 and 4 the output should be 4
the thing I tried

```
def nearestPower(A, B):
    x=math.floor(math.log(B,A))

    x=x+1
    
    number1=A**x
    
    number2=A**x
    
    if(abs(number1-B)>abs(number2-B)):
    
        return number2
    
    else:
    
        return number1
```

actually I have no idea how to solve it so I am asking it I just started leaning python

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the right idea with `math.floor(math.log(B,A))`. But why are you making number1 and number2 the same? The point of `x=x+1` is to make number2 the *next* power of A after number1, *e.g.*

```
def nearestPower(A, B):
    x=math.floor(math.log(B,A))

    number1=A**x
    x=x+1
    number2=A**x
    
    if(abs(number1-B)>abs(number2-B)):
    
        return number2
    
    else:
    
        return number1
```

Comment: is there any another way without importing math will be awesome please tell me thank you

Comment: Yes. Instead of math, you can write a `while` loop with a counter. You start with `i=0` and each time it loops, do `A = A*A` and `i++`, until A > B. Then your 2 X values are `i-1` and `i`, and you can find the closer one.